Non-restrictive clauses and commas
Do I need the comma in this sentence? If so, what is the grammatical basis behind it?

The significance of the color blue in the poem has long been a point of focus for scholars, largely due to the pervasive imagery throughout the text.


I'm thinking you need it, because the clause is, um, non-restrictive, just like with
parenthetical commas.

Commas mean pauses.

If you were reading the sentence out loud you would need to make a slight pause at that point.

The comma makes what comes after it secondary in importance, as a supplementary detail or an interesting fact. Additional information.

@YosefBaskin I thought "restrictive/non-restrictive" terminology applied only to relative clauses. Here a prepositional phrase is set off with commas from the principal clause.

The comma is optional in this exact context. The entire text that follows is essentially a "whole sentence adverb" - if that was moved to the start of the utterance, it would be an optional stylistic choice whether to follow it by a comma. But if the adverbial clause was positioned immediately after the actual verb it modifies (has), it would be idiomatically (still not syntactically) necessary to set it off with commas / pauses: The significance of the color blue in the poem has, largely due to the pervasive imagery throughout the text, long been a point of focus for scholars.

Even a phrase or word can serve as a side comment, really. That's what a non-restrictive modifier is, just so. See really and just so, largely due to usage.
